# How do you find the first order partial derivatives of a function that contains another derivable function?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

As the title says, I have a function which contains another derivable function and I need to find the first order partial derivatives of the bigger function. Can anyone guide me through this?

Ex: $ F(x,y)=x^2 * y * h(x^2+y^2)$, where $h$ is a derivable function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean "differentiable", I believe. Use the product and chain rules
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=2xyh(x^2+y^2)+2x^3yh'(x^2+y^2)
$$
and similarly for $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$.

Comment: And I take $ h'(x^2+y^2)$ separately and calculate it there?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Do I leave the $h$ function like that? Or do I take it aside and calculate it's differential?

Comment: as of right now, I know nothing about $h$ other than that it's differentiable, if $h(z)=\cos(z)$ for example, then yes you can say more about what that expression is equal to

Comment: Mhm that makes sense. Thank you very much!